# The "expressions without prepositions"

Tags: expressions, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

> We do not normally use prepositions in some common expressions.
>
> - Let’s discuss your plans.
>
>   She married a rich business man.
>
>   The baby resembles its father

- Is there a rule behind such expressions and do we have a specific name for these expressions.

Comment: This question is probably better asked in our sister site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It may be best to forget prepositions to start with. I'd look at (1) basic sentence structures {eg [Tang](http://wmtang.org/resources/7-basic-sentence-patterns/)}; (1a) S-V-O {eg Nordquist's article](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/Svo-Subject-Verb-Object.htm)} etc, then (2) prepositional phrases, then (3) multi word verbs (often called phrasal verbs).

Comment: Why do you need a name for such expressions? This is the gist of all I know. The verbs- discuss, marry,and resemble- are usually followed by "direct objects" without prepositions.

Comment: They're called transitive verbs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires the best part of a basic course in English grammar for a reasonable answer.

Comment: I think the one answer below provides a good reason to allow the question...  he might not be asking for how to use the basic grammar,  but the history and theory behind the usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an influential theory of grammar, Case Grammar, according to which both subjects and objects have various cases which would require prepositions in positions other than subject or object.  Although later his theory was couched in more abstract terms, the early paper "A Proposal Concerning English Prepositions" by Charles Fillmore has a rule that deletes the inherent preposition that goes with various subjects and objects in English.  A previous paper by Barbara Hall proposes a similar and more limited syntactic analysis (I think the title was "Subject and Object in English").

Comment: how about links to the papers somewhere (even if behind paywall)  to make it an even stronger answer ?